# Efficient way to retrieve all the rows from cassandra DB

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a table in cassandra with below definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT_INV (
Product_Code TEXT,
Storecode TEXT,
StoreType TEXT,
ProductInfo TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ((Product_Code, Storecode, StoreType)));
```

Now i want to get the list of all the Product_Code which is specific to Storecode and StoreType.
What is the most efficient way to do the same. The table can contains large number of records.

For e.g:

```
Product_Code    Storecode   StoreType   ProductInfo
12  601 Retail      ABC
12  601 Supermart   ABC
13  601 Retail  DEF
14  701 Retail  QWE
13  601 Supermart   ZXC
```

The result should be:

```
Storecode: 601
StoreType: Retail
List of Product_Code : 12,13

Storecode: 601
StoreType : Supermart
List of Product_Code : 12,13

Storecode: 701
StoreType: Retail
List of Product_Code:14
```

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra data modelling is all about denormalisation. If in doubt, denormalising is usually the most efficient way to do something.

In this case, if you create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_codes_by_store (
product_code TEXT,
storecode TEXT,
store_type TEXT
PRIMARY KEY ((storecode, store_type), product_code));
```

Now you can make this query to get all the product codes:

`SELECT * FROM product_codes_by_store WHERE storecode = 'aaa' AND store_type = 'bbb';`

This method is very efficient because Cassandra only needs to hit a single partition (and therefore a single node) in order to fulfil the query.

There are a couple of things you need to keep in mind, however:

1. If there will be a large number of results you will probably need to paginate so the query doesn't time out. Here's the documentation for the Java driver on how to do this: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/paging/
2. Since I've added a clustering column here (`product_code`), you'll need to make sure that the partitions defined by `(storecode, store_type)` will not be too large. It's recommended that you keep partitions under 100MB where possible, as very large partitions can lead to performance issues. There is a bit of leeway here though - if you're a bit over 100MB it's not too bad, especially on newer versions of Cassandra which have better support fo large partitions (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11206).